# Non-readonly fields referenced in GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

Started with overriding concepts and I override the methods `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Primarily I came up with this "very simple code":

```
internal class Person
    {
        public string name;

        public int age;

        public string lname;

        public Person(string name, int age, string lname)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.lname = lname;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var person = obj as Person;
            if (person != null)
            {
                return person.age == this.age && person.name == this.name && person.lname == this.lname;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.age.GetHashCode() * this.name.GetHashCode() * this.lname.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

While this works great, my "co-developer" Mr.Resharper gave me some suggestions:

1. **Non-readonly fields referenced in GetHashCode()**. Suggestions came in this line of code:

`return this.age.GetHashCode() * this.name.GetHashCode() * this.lname.GetHashCode();`

2. **Should we use GetHashCode only for Properties?**

Comment: > Is there any guide-lines for devising it Well, what if [guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) are given by Eric himself.

Comment: Hashing is designed to provide a value that isn't likely change for a given object - hence it's best to depend on readonly fields. Any reason not to make the fields readonly, or do you need to change them after creation of each Person object?

Comment: @Baldrick: Okay. But, consider the scenario that `age` is gonna change every year. So, it might get updated. So, keeping this in mind, how to write to implement `GetHashCode` correctly ?

Comment: Put date of birth in instead, and compute the age as needed, from an 'age' property. Either that, or just don't include 'age' in your hashing.

Comment: @Baldrick: Yup, I could do that! so, what should I do now ? Change the fields to `readonly` in the `Person` class and instead of `age` I use `dob`. ?

Comment: Yep, any fields that don't change after creation - make them readonly. Then either leave 'age' out, or use DOB instead. Then you can call GetHashCode on the DateTime object, and include it in your hash.

Comment: New link to Eric's "[guidelines](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/)" since the @Ehsan's link goes to the root devblogs page.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To summarise what was discussed in the comments:

Hashing is designed to provide a value that doesn't change for a given object, no matter what happens to it - hence it's best to depend only on readonly fields in your GetHashCode method.

Firstly, I would suggest making the `name` and `lname` field readonly, because they probably don't change in your usage scenario.

As for `age`, this is something that changes regularly, so probably best to store a `DateTime` for date of birth, which never changes. Then you can make that readonly too.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the value of a field, used in the hash calculation, after the object had been added to a hash based container like Dictionary or HashSet, you are essentially breaking the inner state of the container. Why is that? Because the object had been stored in a bucket corresponding to a hash value based on its initial state. When the state is changed, e.g. 'age' is modified, the object will continue to live in its old bucket in the hash container although this is not the correct bucket based on its current hash code. This can lead to pretty messy behaviour and a lot of headaches. I've written an [article](https://vkontech.com/gethashcode-pitfalls/) on this topic with some very specific examples, so you may want to check it out.

Comment: I understand the point. But what if I have a class with several ```{ get; set; }``` properties and simply want to compare two instances? I need Equals methods and it requires GetHashCode. And then I get the same error as OP and start searching on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like the idea of having directly public fields this way.

I would prefer properties, and unless I really needed to change them, I'd limit access to them using the relatively new *init* [feature from c# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#init-only-setters):

```
// Will only be setable from the constructor. This will effectively make the
// values read-only (and allow them to be used to generate hashes without
// resharper complaining).
public string name {get; init; } 
public string lname {get; init; }
    
// Note: I'd also use an unchanging date for birth:
public DateTime BirthDate {get; init; };

// Add logic below to actually calculate the age here based 
// on the diff between current date and birth date above.
public int Age {
    get { return ... };
    private set;
};
```